# Monitor has single ripple distortion

Tags: mac, display

Lately, my iMac monitor shows an annoying 'ripple' that is horizontal and evident when I scroll with my magic mouse. I have not run any diagnostic tests to see what reports might show, but I have run Disk Utility and  AppleJack. No change. This 'ripple' moves down the screen slowly too. 
Any suggestions how to proceed?
iMac - Leopard v10.5.8
  Model Identifier: iMac7,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:  2 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 4 MB
  Memory:   4 GB
  Bus Speed:    800 MHz

Answer (score 0):

- First, check the cord connecting the monitor to the graphics card.
- Check the video card installed in a slot.  Connect a different
  monitor if all is well, the problem is either the monitor or the
  computer power supply.
- If not, then the problem of computer power supply or video card. There is another option - a bad installation of the components in the case and if the housing is metal, then maybe you have a short circuit to ground.  Indicator screwdriver or multimeter will allow you to figure out a problem. Well, or you can be an indicator because you will have to pinch or beat current).

If you are not confident in their abilities are best left to professionals repair.

- Use ferrite core cable.

[image]

or add it:

[image]